# Can't switch between tabs in terminal using the shortcuts (Linux Manjaro)

Tags: linux, terminal, shortcuts, manjaro

According to the terminal preferences shortcuts are enabled and I'm using the default settings, so to switch to tab 1 pressing ALT + 1 should do the trick. But it doesn't. Instead I get this output:

```
(arg: 1)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you use Gnome terminal?

Comment: Yes i used Gnome

Comment: Found [this](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/adv-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30224/how-to-disable-the-alt-hotkey-behavior-on-gnome-terminal).

Answer (score 1):

The info from the second link from @Biswapriyo's comment, [How to disable the alt-hotkey behavior on gnome terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30224/how-to-disable-the-alt-hotkey-behavior-on-gnome-terminal%20suggested%20it%20for%20me.) - worked for me:

Under Preferences/General, uncheck "Enable mnemonics (such as Alt-F to open the File menu)".

Comment: Good catch! Actually I was not aware about this. It's saved the day.